# Rebooted without updating Grub menu, can't boot into Ubuntu

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, reboot

I ended up doing a `sudo apt-get autoremove` command earlier to clear up a massive culmination of unneeded packages before using Pinguy Builder, and noted that one of the package removals did a `sudo update-initramfs` type command, except that it didn't update (`-u`), but instead removed the current ramfs file and added a new one. It said "you may need to update grub," as in do `sudo update-grub` and `sudo update-grub2`. However, I was in a hurry to leave for somewhere and shut down the system before doing said `update-grub` commands. Next time I booted, it didn't show any of the linux menu items, just the Android that I installed earlier. Is there any way (preferably without needing an install medium, seeing as I don't have one on hand) to be able to get the system to boot Ubuntu again so that I can do the Grub update commands (and also, would updating the Grub config file fix this or is it a deeper problem?)

- thanks!

Comment: If i is required, I'll boot from a USB... But I'd like to know if you can do the `sudo update-grub` command from the live instance and still have the same effect as if it was on the hard drive. Is it posible, or not?

Comment: Boot live instance, then `mkdir target`, `mount your-filesystem-root /target`, `for f in dev proc run sys; do mount --bind /$f /target/$f; done`, `chroot /target` and you are in a fully functional instance of Ubuntu on your root filesystem. You can then `sudo update-grub` and really anything exactly as if you had booted in the actual installation. When finished `exit` the chroot, `cd /`, `for f in dev proc run sys; do umount /target/$f; done`, `umount /target`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can boot your PC by LiveUSB or LiveCD and then:

```
sudo mkdir /media/target
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/target # mount root
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/target/boot # mount /boot
sudo mount -t proc proc /media/target/proc/ # mount /proc
sudo mount --rbind /sys /media/target/sys/ # recursively mount /sys
sudo mount --rbind /dev /media/target/dev/ # recursively mount /dev

sudo chroot /media/target
```

Then inside chroot run this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I managed to chroot to the right directories, but upon doing `sudo update-grub` as root or as regular live user, I get the "`E: Cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).`"

Comment: Is it UEFI? If so this old instructions (for BIOS) won't work. You also need to mount the ESP (EFI System Partition).

Comment: I ended up reinstalling, but luckily I was able to fetch some 70 GB of files off the old install. Thanks for the help, though!